# How to MySQL Between used for Higher value to Lower value?

Tags: mysql, sql, between

Here I mentioned query:

lowerValue = 3,
upperValue = 6

```
SELECT * FROM SampleTable where tableDay BETWEEN 'lowerValue' AND 'upperValue';
```

This query is working fine, but I need given below query type

lowerValue = 3,
upperValue = 6

```
SELECT * FROM SampleTable where tableDay BETWEEN 'upperValue' AND 'lowerValue';
```

It's return as empty list, because both values are dynamic, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sometimes you just have to sit back and wonder.

Comment: Rules are like this *expr BETWEEN min AND max*: *If expr is greater than or equal to min and expr is less than or equal to max, BETWEEN returns 1, otherwise it returns 0*. [Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a quickfix you could go with [GREATEST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) / [LEAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) comparison functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM   SampleTable
WHERE  tableDay BETWEEN LEAST(upperValue, lowerValue) AND
                        GREATEST(upperValue, lowerValue);
```

but if `upperValue` can be lesser than `lowerValue` then use different names.

Answer (score 1):

Your first argument must always be the lower one.

From documentation of SQL:

```
test_expression [ NOT ] BETWEEN begin_expression AND end_expression
```

**BETWEEN** returns **TRUE** if the value of test_expression is greater than or equal to the value of **begin_expression** and less than or equal to the value of **end_expression**.